# Apache Spark: how to create a counter

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, counter, cloudera-cdh

I'm doing my first steps with scala. I work with Cloudera VM.

I have a csv separate with ;. I want to split each line and to create a val loans with a sequential counter. I wrote a map to do these tasks.

My code is below

```
scala> val loans: RDD[(VertexId, ComplaintNodeDate)] =
 |  sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/complaints_loan.csv").filter(!_.startsWith("DateReceived")).
 | map {line => 
 | val row = line split ';'
 | var initialValue1 = initialValue2 + 1L
 |  initialValue2 = initialValue1
 | (initialValue2, ComplaintLoan(row(0),row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4)))
 | }
```

I get the following error

```
 java.io.IOException: Failed to create local dir in /tmp/spark-3940587c-c7b4-460c-be02-02660ed17f05/blockmgr-d5286d12-401a-4d68-b8b9-7654d319800d/21.
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.getFile(DiskBlockManager.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.contains(DiskStore.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$getCurrentBlockStatus(BlockManager.scala:404)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:805)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:637)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putSingle(BlockManager.scala:991)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1051)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.hadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:761)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:589)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:54)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:56)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:58)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:60)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:62)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:64)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:66)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:68)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:70)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:72)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:74)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:76)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:78)
at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:80)
at $iwC.<init>(<console>:82)
at <init>(<console>:84)
at .<init>(<console>:88)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:874)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:874)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:874)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:874)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:874)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:874)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:874)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:656)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:669)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:996)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


 scala>
```

Is it right my code?

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to run `spark-shell` and `spark-submit` on behalf of user `spark` in Cloudera:

```
sudo -u spark spark-shell
```

2) By default, Spark reads data into DataFrame from HDFS, so you need to upload it first (using hdfs command-line tool or Hue File Browser). If you want read data from driver's local filesystem, specify explicit protocol `file:///home/data/file.txt`

3) Use [`zipWithIndex`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zipWithIndex%28%29) on your RDD to get rows numbered:

```
loans.zipWithIndex()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to maintain a counter by local variable, but if you want to attach an id to your record. You can create one separately, zip it with your `loans` file and then transform it into something you want.

```
val numOfPartitions = 8
val loans = sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/complaints_loan.csv", numOfPartitions).
               filter(!_.startsWith("DateReceived"))

val loansWithId = sc.parallelize(1 to loans.count.toInt, numOfPartitions).
                     zip(loans).map{ line =>
                     val row = line._2.split(';')
                     (line._1, ComplaintLoan(row(0),row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4)))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I checked your code. But I get the following message when I create loansWithID
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/home/cloudera/complaints_loan.csv
 at 
Could you help me to fix the error?. I work with Cloudera V

Comment: As the error suggests, it doesn't find the complaints file. Try this command 'hadoop -fs -put localPathTo/complaints_loan.csv /home/cloudera' before you start spark-shell, or run spark-submit.